# Posting large image to database via web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to save a 3036x4048 photo to an SQL database. I've converted it to a base64 string using Javascript but whenever I try to post it to my web api the object shows up as null. I can save smaller photos without a problem so I know the web api works. According to my research the max length that a byte[] can store is 2,146,435,071. The image I'm attempting to post has a length of 9,218,020. I've also looked at the image size and it's around 6 MB. I also manually inserted this image into the database and it accepts it just fine. So why can't my web api handle a larger image? Is the image size (6 MB) too big?

Here's a bit of code. Not sure if it'll help.

```
public class TicketPhoto
{
    public int PhotoID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

 public static TicketPhoto SaveTicketPhoto(TicketPhoto tcktPhoto)
    {
        TicketPhoto ticketPhoto = new TicketPhoto();

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable ticketPhotoTable = new DataTable();
            ticketPhotoTable.Columns.Add("PHOTO_ID", typeof(int));
            ticketPhotoTable.Columns.Add("PHOTO", typeof(byte[]));
            ticketPhotoTable.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", typeof(string));

            ticketPhotoTable.Rows.Add(
                                        tcktPhoto.PhotoID,
                                        tcktPhoto.Photo,
                                        tcktPhoto.PhotoData,
                                      );

            using (connection)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spSMSaveTicketPhoto", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter tblParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblTicketPhoto", ticketPhotoTable);
                tblParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return ticketPhoto;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know C# nor ASP.net, but posting your API code would probably help other folks answer your question better.

Comment: I don't think the code is going to help here but I've posted it.

Comment: The object is null on being bound? What does fiddler etc show you sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to set `maxRequestLength` in `web.config` explicitly. The [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx) is 4MB.

E.g. 51200 for 50MB.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very, very much Win!